# upload image and draw rectangles using only one ImageView

Tags: android, drawing, android-imageview, android-canvas

Can I upload a picture (in a ImageView) and draw rectangles using the canvas in the same ImageView? all the examples I've seen so far used two. I wonder if you can use only one? if so, how?

Comment: sure: extend `BitmapDrawable` and override `draw` method (easy way), or extend `ImageView` and override `onDraw` method (a bit harder)

Comment: I started working with android a short time, you would have some example to show me? I thank you for your help

Comment: why not use the image view inside a view with border 1.

Comment: first try something by yourself, if still in problems, write here

Comment: how would I do that? that way I could draw rectangles freely about the image?

Comment: you know somewhere there might be something for me to build me? or something that can help me understand how it would use these ways?

Comment: `draw rectangles freely` you mean with your finger or what?

Comment: I have a code that you can do this, but it uses two ImageView and how the same application I need to zoom and pan, and is difficult to do this using two, I believe that using only one ImageView be simpler

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to android. 
Open android studio, . 
File ->New->import Sample , 
search for image. 
Choose basic render script, this will give you basics of image handling. 
[image]
However for your usage, you can simply create a view with border and add imageview inside it.

Comment: That his idea to  create a view with border and add imageview inside it be like? and the draw rect would be on this ImageView?

Comment: No thats my idea to make the view with borders and imageview. It will give the same effect with lot less code.